# Usage of setimeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript, settimeout

What will be the output of following program and why?

```
setTimeout(function() {
     console.log("hi");
}, 0);

 //Do some calculation for 3-4 secs or more over here
console.log("Bye");
```

I am unable to simulate as I am not sure how to put 3-4 secs calculation. Also if the value is Bye and than Hi, why is that?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the code?

Comment: [RTM - Mozilla Dev Network - setTimeout() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setTimeout "Mozilla Dev Network: setTimeout() reference")

Comment: @meza it was asked from me in the interview. The interviewer has written 0 secs as the delay.

Comment: @AeroX Sorry, I did not find setTimeout with 0 ms as delay in the link you gave. Can you please throw some lights on it. Thanks

Comment: @RohitManglik Towards the bottom of that article there is a section titled "Minimum/maximum delay and timeout nesting". Under there is explains what happens with short time-out values (including 0).

Comment: Here is how to simulate 4sec of computation:  `var start = Date.now(); while (Date.now() - start < 4000);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is 
1.Bye
2.hi

Why? The function is given to the callstack by setTimeout even if the timeout is 0 msec's, but before that there is the console.log("Bye") already at the end of the callstack. That is why it is executed earlier.